# Given a string of text and HTML formats to be applied to the string, how can i generate a valid HTML string. In python

Tags: python

```
Given a string of text and HTML formats to be applied to the string, generate a valid HTML string.

text = 'ABCDEFGHIJ'
format = {
    'bold': [(0,4)],
    'italics': [(2,6)]
}

output = '<b>AB<i>CD</i></b><i>EF</i>GHIJ'

Note: You need to close </i> at index 4 and then add it back in order to have valid HTML tags
```

I'm stumped on how to begin this, I thought about going through the the formats to be applied and order by index:
[(0, 'bold'), (2, 'italics'), (4, 'bold'), (6, 'italics')]

Comment: I would reorganize the data into a list with the character position and the action ('start bold', 'end bold', etc).  Now, I can sort by character number and go through the list sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: You can construct a stack with each of the styles so newer styles are forced to be popped before the one you need is. So in your example, you can push bold on to the stack then italics. When you have to pop bold, you find italics first so you put that on another stack and find bold. After you pop bold, you can pop items off the second stack and back on the first.

so at character 4, you have

| Stack1 | Stack2 |
| --- | --- |
| bold |  |
| italics |  |

then

| Stack1 | Stack2 |
| --- | --- |
|  | bold |

finally

| Stack1 | Stack2 |
| --- | --- |
| bold |  |